# How Can I Use Buttons to Control Navigation in Root View, Instead of Table Cells?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sdk

I'm developing my first iPhone app, which is a navigation based one. I want to know how I can use icons/buttons [like this app](http://static.apptrackr.org/itunes/4/318404385-1318995808/screenshot0_1318996382_9bb5a15a1ac95f5c13474438231265a6.jpg) in the root view to control navigation instead of the default table cell view.

I would appreciate some step by step guide since I'm sort of newbie and didn't get how to do this, reading the documentations, or similar questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than starting with a Navigation based app, start with a window based app and create an instance of UINavigationController in app delegate (in method appDidFinishLaunching) and set any UIviewController as it's root view controller. You can then do whatever customizations in that view controller

Finally set the navigationController as rootviewController of you application window.

```
UIViewController *myCustomRootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *myNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myCustomRootViewController];
[myCustomRootViewController release];
self.window.rootViewController = myNavController;
[myNavController release];
```

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a very n00bish, dumb question, but can I start with a view-based app? I have the rss and rss parsing classes, and following this link: http://timneill.net/2010/09/modal-view-controller-example-part-1/ I could add the buttons, too. Only the actions are left! Just want to make sure I can continue with a view-based app.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to use google, or anywhere else on Stack Overflow before you ask a question. I found [this](http://timneill.net/2010/09/modal-view-controller-example-part-1/) in a minute. If you're adding to a navigation controller (which is what handles views in a table view), then use `– pushViewController:animated:` instead of `presentModalViewController:animated:` And after you push or present a view controller, don't forget to release it if you are not using automatic reference counting.